# Log-concavity of $g$ on $(a,b)$ implies $g'(x)/g(x)$ is monotone decreasing on $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms

This has been stated like a trivial implication in the article that I'm reading. However I can't figure out how does the result hold. Here is how I've been thinking about this;

Since $g$ is log concave on $(a,b)$, 
$$\ln((1-\alpha) g(x) + \alpha g(y))\geq (1-\alpha) \ln g(x) + \alpha \ln g(y)$$
or 
$$\ln g(y) - \ln g(x) \leq \ln g(x))' |g(y)-g(x)|$$

I think this last equation should help show the result but I can't work it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can be assumed that $g$ is twice differentiable?

Comment: Yes, it's twice-differentiable real-valued function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If function $f$ is concave then $f''(x) \leq 0$. A function is log-concave if $\log(f(x))$ is concave. Hence, $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\log(g(x))\right] = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\right] \leq 0$$ for any $x\in (a,b)$. Since the derivative of $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$ is negative for all $x\in (a,b)$ it is monotonically decreasing on $(a,b)$.